# How to choose just one picture and give its title?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Here's my situation: my code will plot a lot of pictures using matplotlib. After it I want to 
choose the best one and to give it a title with the others images not closed yet (I am trying 
to get some picture and change it). Have matplotlib a way to rank the image files,
something like 'fignum=100'?

Edit: The plots will appear in different windows and is desired to change the image programmatically, or by GUI window at least. I don't have a particular reason to identify that figure at runtime, maybe it will make this work easier (I'm not sure about it!).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, matplotlib does have a `fignum` property. But, there is simply not enough information in the question, to provide a useful answer. Are the plots created in different windows? Do you need to set the title programmatically or within the GUI window? What would be the reason to identify a figure at runtime; what should be accomplished by that? You may [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: Assuming you are just creating a lot of figures, you can do `fig = plt.figure(); ax = fig.add_subplot(111); graph = ax.plot(x,y)` and you can change the figure's title afterwards with `fig.suptitle('title')`. You can also keep a list of figures instead of making a variable out of each one: `list_of_figs = []; list_of_figs.append(plt.figure()); ax =list_of_figs[-1].add_subplot(111)` and so on and so forth.

Comment: I'm glad with your feedback :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interactive window, you can use the "Figure Options" button
[image]
to set a new title to a figure:

[image]